# Organizing / segmenting WCF methods within a single service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

We currently have an organizational mess of old ASMX services, and some newer WCF services, which are hosted in IIS.

In the past, if we had 10 different vendors that needed an API, we would have 10 different WCF services, and it would be an organizational mess, not to mention the duplication of config and keeping track of which services do what.

I want to combine this all to a single WCF service, with a single .svc file and a single endpoint. I'd like to know how can I still segment or organize methods (i.e. at the OperationContract level)?  For example, if I have one set of methods that processes some student data, and another that processes financial data, and I wanted to organize them into their own separate groups, how can I do that?  I know I can control authorization to use the methods by using roles; so I'd just like to clarify that authorization is not what I'm asking about.  I want to know about how to best organize the code; it doesn't look like I can define a namespace at the OperationContract level.  I don't really see any attribute at the OperationContract level that would fit my needs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can define and implement multiple interfaces on one service and they each get their own endpoint.
You can go as far as to have one interface for each vendor. Where there is shared code/functionality the separate interfaces can delegate down to the same classes/dlls.

For vendors that are very similar you can share interfaces or have the individual vendor interfaces inherit from a "base" interface.

Using this method if you ever decide to go with different physical services for some vendors it is very easy to do.

Yes you do have a separate endpoint for each interface, but they share the same base address, service and `bindingConfiguration` (assuming they use the same protocol) so it is not hard to maintain. I have had success with this pattern. I think it maintains enough separation that things do not get too tightly coupled but shares as much configuration as is practical.
Here is a sample server side config exposing separate interfaces but sharing service and bindingConfig.

```
<services>
  <service name="namespace.Vendors">
    <clear />
    <endpoint address="Vendor1" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="HTTPBindingConfig" name="Vendor1HTTP"
      contract="PGF.Business.IVendor1" listenUriMode="Explicit">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="Vendor2" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="HTTPBindingConfig" name="Vendor2HTTP"
      contract="PGF.Business.IVendor12" listenUriMode="Explicit">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If I did as you suggest, would I just have multiple endpoints that all have the same URL pointing at the same .svc file?  I'm trying to have just one URL for this service.  I'd also like to have all the binding / authentication / authorization config for this service be the same without any extra work to implement it; would that be the case in your scenario too?

Comment: I updated my answer, but if you need to share the same endpoint this is clearly not the way to go.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.  What you've mentioned makes sense, and I think I might have found some documentation on how to have multiple services share the same URL and same .svc file...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210.aspx     However, I don't know if this is how I'd like to go about organizing my webservice.  I'd have preferred if you could set a namespace per OperationContract, but I don't think that's possible.  Instead, I think I will just organize it by using a partial interface and organize functionality between different cs files.